# Improper functioning tableView data and recharging

Tags: ios, tableview, reloaddata

-Hi, I have a problem with a tableview reloading data and what I want to do is that you put the selected cell in blue and change an image that is, the problem is that if I make the [self.mytableview reloadData] in the didselectedRow blue background disappears and if I do the image of the cell does not change,  I'm a bit lost with this piece of code I give thanks

```
if (indexPath.row == _selectedRow) {

            UIImageView *favView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favIconSelected.png"]];
            CGRect frame = favView.frame;
            frame.origin.x = 294;
            frame.origin.y = 7;
            favView.frame = frame;

            [cell.contentView addSubview:favView];

            [favView release];
        }

 cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:SELCETED_BGIMGCELL]]autorelease];



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    Product *p = [_productList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    _selectedRow=indexPath.row;
    [_delegate productWasSelected:p];
    [self.myTableView reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `reloadData` at all. All you need to do is to update the cell that was selected.

In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method you can get the cell directly by calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` on the `tableView`. This will return the actual cell that's on display and you can directly set the image it's displaying.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.imageView.image = ...;
```

Alternatively you could control the image display from your cell subclass if you provide it with both the normal and selected images when you configure each instance.

Comment: sorry, I did not understand at all, if I did that to make the [self.mytableview reloadData] not lose everything again?
If you were kind enough to give me an example, thanks

Comment: when you do "reloadData", all previous cells are removed and are created new cells.

Comment: okey, I worked, but now I can think of a problem when I go to another cell, the previous cell with the image stays put when you want to select and return to the original state, which would you recommend?

Comment: That's where doing it in the subclass works because it is called when it gets selected and when it gets deselected.